# Exception when starting WSO2 identity server

Tags: wso2, xacml

I am able to hit the server at: `https://localhost:9443/carbon`, but seeing this exception thrown:

> Could not initialize RMI server java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to
>   URL [rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi]: javax.nam
>   ing.CommunicationException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-J RMP server at remote endpoint]
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConn
>   ectorServer.java:804)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServ
>   er.java:417)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager.startJMXService(JMXServerM
>   anager.java:121)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.comple
>   teInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:194)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.servic
>   eChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:279)

Comment: Do you have any other Java processes running?

Comment: Looks like this is a common issue. 

https://www.google.com/search?q=non-JRMP+server+at+remote+endpoint 

Do you always get that error? Which version of WSO2 identity server you are using. What is your operating system and Java version? Will you be able to try using Oracle JDK?

Comment: Yes i believe i did and restarting computer fixed this error

Answer (score 0):

You're having some sort of port conflict.  I encounter this same exception if I have another certain appserver/webserver already running.  In my experience it doesn't seem to happen if have a Tomcat already running, but if I'm running JBoss before I start Identity Server, I will get these exceptions.

For reference I'm using Identity Server 5.0.0, Tomcat 7.x, JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6.1+.  At least in my case, everything I need to run still works. :)